# JSON (Flickr) in AS3

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flickr

In AS3 (Flash) I need to insert a Flickr feed. I want the Flickr images to show in a kind of gallery. This is my JSON for the Flickr images: http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=snow&format=json
I've got this code, showing a jpg-image. But how do I make it show JSON?

`var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader(); var image:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://natur.suntuubi.se/datafiles/gallery/1/lejon%20som%20ryter.jpg‌​"); imageLoader.load(image); addChild (imageLoader); imageLoader.x = 200; imageLoader.y = 300;`

Answer (score 0):

You would use `URLLoader` and the `JSON` class to load and parse the JSON string:

```
function loadFeed():void 
{
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=snow&format=json"));
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
}

function onComplete(e:Event):void 
{
    var jsonStr:String = String(e.target.data);

    var jsonObj:Object = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
}
```

Please note, however, that according to [this link](http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157622950514923/), the JSON being produced by the API is invalid. I would suggest using the XML result instead (accessible via `http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=snow&format=xml`)